# Image Not Shown on Html Page

Tags: java, html

[image]

I used Java SE and MS SQL Database.IN JTextPane.setContentType(html)
how can show image on html, because i have only ImagIcon(not extension)

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to put more of your code here, what is `MemberImage`? Which class? what this method getIcon() returns? is it an URL, an object, base64 string? for the HTML to be able to show an image you need to inform a valid address for the page, passing an entire object won't help.

Comment: MemeberImae is a JLabel Object and getIcon() returns ImageIcon Objects.
is it possible java ImageIcon set to html images.

thanks for reply

Comment: Sir, I Also Have Byte Array[] in the Given ImageIcon.
Can i Used Byte Array in Html Code to show Image??

Comment: is there any possible to JLabel Image Set on Html <img> ?
thanks.